# Swift , Trying to sort array by object property type string, objects conforms to comparable protocol

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sorting, comparable

I want to **sort** new employee array on basis of string not ID , I am able to sort it on ID property but not for Name Property.Tried

```
var newEmployeeArray = employeeArray.sorted(by:{$0.Name<$1.Name})
```

But not working

```
class employee:Comparable {
var id = 10
var name = "Deepak"
init(){

}
init(Id:Int , Name:String){
    self.id = Id
    self.name = Name
}
static func == (lhs:employee, rhs:employee)->Bool{
    return lhs.id==rhs.id && lhs.name == rhs.name
}
static func < (lhs:employee, rhs:employee)->Bool{
    //Have i written this logic correct?
    if(lhs.id != rhs.id){
        return lhs.id<rhs.id
    }else{
        return lhs.name<rhs.name
    }
}
}
var a1 = employee(Id:15,Name:"Deepak")
var b1 = employee(Id:10,Name:"Shekhar")
var employeeArray = [a1,b1]

var newEmployeeArray = employeeArray.sorted(by:{$0.Name<$1.Name})//Not working

//var newEmployeeArray = employeeArray.sorted()// Working for ID

print(newEmployeeArray[0].id,newEmployeeArray[1].id,separator:",")
```

I expect the newEmployeeArray to be sorted on name property.

Comment: If I change `$0.Name` to `$0.name` (and the same for `$1.Name`) your code works for me. You should try and stick to convention. Only class, enum and struct names begin with a capital, variables, arguments, properties etc start with a lower case letter.  In your code, the array is already sorted by name.

Answer (score 1):

As `Paulw11` states, you should stick to naming conventions.

You can find some information here:

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Variables starts with a lower case letter and your property `name` in your class `employee` (which should by the way be called `Employee`) starts with a lower case letter which is good. But then to access it you should call `name` with a lower case letter.

var newEmployeeArray = employeeArray.sorted(by:{ $0.name < $1.name })

Have a nice day,

```
Vincent
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `employeeArray.sorted(by:{$0.Name<$1.Name})` to `employeeArray.sorted(by:{$0.name<$1.name})` as swift language is case sensitive.

Also, you do not have to conform to Comparable protocol if you want to pass the return statement in the block.

```
   if(lhs.id != rhs.id){
     return lhs.id<rhs.id
    }else{
     return lhs.name<rhs.name
    }
```

Now in this block of code as id's are different, the else block is never executed.

The array will be sorted according to name once the ids are same.

If you want the array to be sorted according to name:

```
static func < (lhs:Employee, rhs:Employee)->Bool{
        return lhs.name<rhs.name
}
```